# Error in computing outliers

Tags: r, outliers

I'm trying to compute multivariate outliers with the mahalanobis distance in R, but I get a warning message when I try to plot my results.

Illustrated here,

```
# install.packages(c("mlbench"), dependencies = TRUE)
library(mlbench)
data(Glass)

mydata.numeric.scaled<-scale(Glass[,-10],center=T)
# install.packages(c("mvoutlier"), dependencies = TRUE)
library(mvoutlier)
alpha.value = 0.05
alpha.value.penalizado = 1 - ( 1 - alpha.value) ^ (1/nrow(mydata.numeric.scaled)) 
uni.plot(mydata.numeric.scaled,symb=FALSE, alpha = alpha.value.penalizado)
```

However, instead of a plot I get this error/warning:

> Error in plot.window(...) :'ylim' needs finite values
>
> In addition: Warning message:
>   In covMcd(x, alpha = quan) :
>     The 112-th order statistic of the absolute deviation of variable 8 is zero.
>   There are 176 observations (in the entire dataset of 214 obs.) lying on the
>   hyperplane with equation a_1*(x_i1 - m_1) + ... + a_p*(x_ip - m_p) = 0 with (m_1,
>   ..., m_p) the mean of these observations and coefficients a_i from the vector a
>   <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0)

What does it mean?

Comment: I can't get to the data. Could you possible provide a _self-contained_ [complete minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) inside this question?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking for. The dataset is so typical. If you put "glass dataset" on google you can see million of entries. And I think, I was minimal and clear on the code and the question, showing the output of the code that it is an error. What more do you need?

Comment: I apologize for not searching for your data set on google to help you solve _your problem_. I simply clicked on the link and I couldn’t get to the website. I should have realized it is a widely used dataset. Silly me. What I need is the dataset you make use of so that I can reproduce your issue. I am trying to help you.

Comment: This is two other links https://www.kaggle.com/uciml/glass , V . Sorry for my link, it is good for me, I dont know why fails fo you.

Comment: possibly better link: http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/glass/

Comment: Thanks a lot. The website you inked to seem to require me to sign up to get access to the data. Regardless, I found the data and added it to your question.

Comment: I realize this might not what you want, but if you go directly on `Glass` from the `mlbench` library and exclude not only `10`, but also `8` and `9` it works, i.e. `uni.plot(Glass[,-c(8:10)])`. It's a start. YOur code also works starting with `mydata.numeric.scaled <-scale(Glass[,-c(8:10)])`. Sure you only has to exude `10`? Is this cheating already?

Comment: Yes, this is my code. Because of I'm computing outliers I have to get all the numeric columns. Yes, I realized that the problematic columns are 8 and 9. But I don't know why I want a theorical statistical answer of what is happening  or how to fix it. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: `pairs(Glass[,-10],gap=0,pch=".")` or `skimr::skim(Glass)` shows that columns 9 and 10 (Fe and Ba) are mostly zeros, with very low mean values. Don't know precisely why this causes problems though.

Comment: I don't know if that could affect or  how it affects to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is on the amount of data that uses to calculate the covMcd. This can be solved by taking the entire dataset setting quan=1. By default quan=1/2 taking a half piece of the dataset.